# Acronis backup of TrueCrypt encrypted hard drive

Tags: truecrypt, acronis-trueimage

Our company will soon be using TrueCrypt to fully encrypt our laptop users' hard drives. Normally, when making an image backup of the laptop, we would do a standard (standard as in mostly using all default options) full image backup with Acronis True Image Home.

Now that we'll be taking advantage of full disk encryption, is it necessary to do sector by sector backups with Acronis, so that it gets every sector of the encrypted data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, only file level backup is supported for this situation according to this [Acronis KB article](http://kb.acronis.com/content/14877).
It lists a work around.

Answer (score 0):

In a bitlocker environment, I had to turn off bitlocker in order to use acronis to make a backup (I was using acronis from a bootable USB).